# Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information with Ajax Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a website and I use Ajax Control Tootkit (7.1005). I installed ajax control toolkit with nuget. 
I use shared hosting and it is Medium Trusted Level.
My problem appear when i try open page which contains ToolkitScriptManager item.

Error Message:

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Source Error: 
Line 53:                             <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
Line 54:                             </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

Stack Trace: 


[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +4
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +61
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerConfig..cctor() +68
```

Page Source:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And also webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

What is my mistake? How can i fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you've resolved this issue, but in case you didn't and for the reference of others who are facing this same issue.

The answer is to replace the version 1.1005 with any other, in my case i did with 4.1.7.123 which is from January 2013.

Comment: Yes, I have resolved issue. However i do not belive my solution is best soluion. Therefore i did not write answer. But you are right, I changed version (one of previous versions) and problem solved. Thank you.